# how to add item source dynamically in win-list-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, windows-8.1, winjs

I have defined a list and template as below. I am defining list item data source from html. Is there any way to bind the item data source dynamically i.e.from javscript. Its an angular-winjs application.

```
  <win-list-view selection-mode="'none'"
                                       id="liqAssetListFlyout"
                                       class="verticalList win-selectionstylefilled win-listview"
                                       style="height: auto;"
                                       item-data-source="LiqFlyout"
                                       itemtemplate="select('.liqListTemplate')">

                            <win-item-template>
                                <div class="liqListTemplate"  data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
                                    <div style="float: left; width: 36%; margin-top: 1.5%;">
                                        <label id={{item.data.index}} class="T20" style="float: left;">{{item.data.assetName}}</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="float: left; width: 33%; margin-top: 1.5%;">
                                        <label class="T20 " style="float: left; ">{{item.data.Internal}}</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="float: left;margin-top: 1.5%;">
                                        <label class="T20 " style="float: left; ">{{item.data.External}}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr ng-if="showHideLine(item.data.assetName)" style="float:left; width:100%;margin-top:2%" />

                            </win-item-template>
                            <win-list-layout></win-list-layout>
                        </win-list-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items[..data..];
var bindList = new WinJS.Binding.List(items);
var listView = document.getElementById("liqAssetListFlyout").winControl;

listView.itemDataSource = bindList.dataSource;
```

that would be the way from javascript